# How to switch on Bezier tools on Grease Pencil?

Tags: bezier-curves, grease-pencil

My present interface looks like this below. No Curve Editing setting in sight.

[image]

This below has Curve Editing. Now, how do I bring that tool into my Edit Mode?

[image]

Comment: It's only in the 2.92 alpha version

Comment: @wilks Thank you. Sorry for my lateness to reply. I cannot wait for 2.92 to come out.

Comment: you can already try it out if you want, here: https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: @wilks. You are a star. Thank you very much.